# Generalized Hurwitz Spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

In this question all the varieties are over $\mathbb{C}$. Classic Hurwitz spaces $\mathcal{H}_{g,r}$ are moduli spaces of simple branched coverings $f \colon X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $d$, where $X$ is a smooth curve ov genus $g$ and there are exactly $r$ branch points. Simple means that every point in $\mathbb{P}^1$ has at least $d-1$ preimages. My question is whether similar moduli spaces were considered for finite branched coverings $X \to \mathbb{P}^k$, for $k > 1$? One of course has to define a corresponding notion of "simple" and classify the branching.

Comment: There are many different ways you could try to extend Hurwitz schemes to higher dimensional projective spaces.  Do you want the branch locus in projective space to be irreducible?

Comment: I think that it makes sense to consider the case where the branch locus is a divisor of normal crossing for example.